# Delete first 5 rows of datatable

Tags: .net, vb.net, datatable

Is it possible to delete the first 5 rows of a datatable?

I tried the below but it deleted every other line.

```
For j as interfere = 0 to lastrow step 1
   Dt.rows.remove (dt.rows (j))
Next
```

Comment: Add a condition of `if j = 5 then exit for`

Comment: It stops at 5 already. It will delete the first line skip the second delete the 3rd and so on

Comment: Try getting of the 'Step 1' part. I know it should be working, but it steps by 1 by default. It's worth a shot.

Comment: You can call `dt.Rows.RemoveAt(0)` for 5 times, but you should check if there is any row to delete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use such code, to remove first 5 rows:

```
For index = 1 To 5
    If (dt.Rows.Count > 0) Then
        dt.Rows.RemoveAt(0)
    End If
Next
```

The if part checks if there is any row to delete.

Comment: Thanks related that works but why is that different than what I had?

Comment: because of what I stated in my answer. the indexes are changing  so if you delete index 0, 1 becomes 0 and your iterator variable increases to 2. Reza's code is removing index 0 each iteration of the loop. Which will guarantee that only the top items are removed.

Comment: You are welcome, you were deleting `dt.rows(j)`. For example if you stored 0,1,2,3,4,... in rows, when you delete 0, then you want to delete rows(1) that is 2.

Comment: Thanks that's what I was thinking but want sure how to account for it

Answer (score 1):

Try it in reverse so that you don't affect the previous row

```
For j as integer = 4 to 0 step -1
  Dt.rows.remove(dt.rows(j))
Next
```

What you're running into is in the first iteration index 0 is removed and the iterator variable becomes 1

in the second iteration what was originally at index 1 is now index 0 in the dt so your are removing index 1 and leaving what was originally 1.

Comment: This solution gives an error if you do not have more than 4 rows in your datatable

Comment: @etalon11 Yes, there is no checking. Once I noticed it, I had already seen Reza's answer which I thought was a better solution than mine.

Comment: Your solution is also good. Instead of going from "4" you got take MIN(4, dt.Rows.Count). Then your solution is better because you are performing less checks on RowCount. This doesn't matter on 5 Rows, but maybe if you have more...